# Userdefault not storing values in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to store some values using `Userdefault` at `application` launching time. Here, I placed userdefault store code inside `appdidfinishlaunching` method and trying to get values into my main `viewcontroller`. application first launch time its not receiving values but second time I am receiving `values`. how to solve this?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if ((UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "From_Name") == nil) && (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "To_Name") == nil)) {

            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            UserDefaults.standard.set("0", forKey: "DFrom_ID") //setObject
        }
```

My MainViewController

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DFrom_ID"))")

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. `return true` belongs to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and "DFrom_ID" != "From_ID".  The behavior is normal because `viewDidLoad` in the view controller is called earlier than `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: if I am storing inside viewdidload also its not storing at first time @vadian

Comment: what you get in `viewDidLoad` print ? can you add breakpoints and debug it

Comment: @vadian i think `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called before `viewDidLoad `

Comment: @Sh_Khan From my experience it's not.

Comment: Its working. the problem is I am getting stored key values globally in main view controller. so Its I moved veiwwill appear then its working. @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated);
    print("\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DFrom_ID"))")
}
```

Remove code from ViewDidLoad to ViewDidAppear method in MainViewController.